# minko / lua issue : premake5.lua:3: attempt to index global 'minko' (a nil value)

Tags: linux, lua, solution, premake, minko

I am working with [minko](http://minko.io/) and managed to compile MINKO SDK properly for 3 platforms (Linux, Android, HTML5) and build all tutorials / examples. Moving on to create my own project, I followed the instructions on how to use the existing skeleton project, then using an existing example project.

(I believe there is an error in the skeleton code at this line :

```
auto sceneManager = SceneManager::create(canvas->context());    //does not compile
```

where as the example file look like this :

```
auto sceneManager = SceneManager::create(canvas);   //compile and generate binary
```

I was able to do so by modifying premake5.lua (to include more plugins) and calling script/solution_gmake_gcc.sh 
to generate the make solution a week ago. Today, I tried to make a new project in a new folder but calling

**script/solution_gmake_gcc.sh** and **script/clean** failed with this error:

*minko-master/skel_tut/mycode/premake5.lua:3: attempt to index global 'minko' (a nil value)*

Now at premake5.lua line 3 there is this line : ***minko***.project.solution(PROJECT_NAME),
however sine i am not familiar with lua at all, can anyone shed any light on the issue ?
What is supposed to be declared here, why is it failing suddenly... ?
(I can still modify,compile and run the code but i can't for example add more plug-ins)

PS: weirdly enough, the previously 'working' project is also failing at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PROJECT_NAME = path.getname(os.getcwd()) 

minko.project.application("minko-tutorial-" .. PROJECT_NAME)

  files { "src/**.cpp", "src/**.hpp", "asset/**" }
  includedirs { "src" }

  -- plugins
  minko.plugin.enable("sdl")
  minko.plugin.enable("assimp")
  minko.plugin.enable("jpeg")
  minko.plugin.enable("bullet")
  minko.plugin.enable("png")
  --html overlay
  minko.plugin.enable("html-overlay")
```

Assuming that's indeed your project `premake5.lua` file (please us the code tags next time), you should have `include "script"` at the beginning of the file:

https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/skeleton/premake5.lua#L1

If you don't have this line, it will not include `script/premake5.lua` which is in charge of including the SDK build system files that defines everything inside the `minko` Lua namespace/table. That's why you get that error.

I think you copy pasted one of the examples/tutorials `premake5.lua` file instead of modifying the one provided by the skeleton. The premake conf file of the examples/tutorials are different since they are included from the SDK premake files. But your app `premake5.lua` does the "opposite": it includes the SDK conf files rather than being included by them.

**The best practice is to edit your app's copy of the skeleton's `premake5.lua`** (instead of copy/pasting one from the examples/tutorials).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was my issue. Since the skeleton project was not compiling, I picked up minko-tutorial-06-load-3d-files and worked from there.
(weirdly it worked last week :-P)

Since the change is just one line, i just modified skeleton main.cpp and got it working and will always use it when i wanna start a new project.

Again, merci :-)

Answer (score 0):

> (I believe there is an error in the skeleton code at this line :

That's possible. Our build server doesn't test the skeleton code. That's a mistake we will fix ASAP to make sure it works properly.

> script/solution_gmake_gcc.sh and script/clean failed with this error:
>
> minko-master/skel_tut/mycode/premake5.lua:3: attempt to index global 'minko' (a nil value)

Could you copy/paste your premake5.lua file?
Also, what's the value you set for the MINKO_HOME env var? Maybe you've moved the SDK...

Note that instead of setting a global MINKO_HOME env var, you can also set the corresponding LUA constant at the very begining of your premake5.lua file.

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback !

This is the content of premake5.lua (taken from the example):

PROJECT_NAME = path.getname(os.getcwd())
minko.project.application("minko-tutorial-" .. PROJECT_NAME)
 files {
  "src/**.cpp",
  "src/**.hpp",
  "asset/**"
 }
 includedirs { "src" }
 -- plugins
 minko.plugin.enable("sdl")
 minko.plugin.enable("assimp")
 minko.plugin.enable("jpeg")
 minko.plugin.enable("bullet")
 minko.plugin.enable("png")
 --html overlay
 minko.plugin.enable("html-overlay")

MINKO_HOME is still the same.
You think lua is unable to find MINKO_HOME and thus creating the issue ?

Comment: I need the premake5.lua of YOUR project. Not the one from another example.

Comment: yes, this is the one used by my project, inspired but modified version of the one of skeleton sample project. (added assimp, html-overlay, turning on jpeg, bullet...)